# Create a Function of a Single Variable in Python from a Function of many

Tags: python, function

My question is motivated by the `scipy.optimize.minimize()` function.

I have an objective function `f(x, const1, const2)` that I would like to minimise for `x` where the values of `const1` and `const2` are constant within `f`.

How do I declare `g(x) = f(x, const1, const2)` so that I can pass `g` to the `minimize()` function?

I am currently using global variables but the solution has become quite messy.

Comment: Have you tried [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#partial-objects)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest/easiest way to do that is probably with the python `partial` function. Specifically, if you pass it a series of args and kwargs, it will return a new function where those inputs are frozen. For instance:

```
from functools import partial
g = partial(f, const1=const1, const2=const2)
```

`g(x)` will then be equivalent to: `f(x, const1=const1, const2=const2)`

You can also do the same as the above with positional args rather than kwargs. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for a more complete treatment.

You *could* do this will a `lambda` function as in testuser's answer, but then you have to deal with the extra overhead, and it kind of violates python's zen:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
g = lambda(x): f(x, const1, const2)
```